# Order Doctrine manyToOne collection differently in different controllers

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Synfony2 with Doctrine, I have an Entity (say Country) with a ManyToOne (say City) relation to another.
I use the @ORM\OrderBy annotation to tell Doctrine how to fetch the association by default.

I want to display the cities ordered by name in a page, and by size in another, so I want the orderBy being different in the two controllers. **Is there a way to tell Doctrine the orderby rule the proxy object should use when hydrating at run time ?**

My current working solution is to have two different methods in the repository to fetch the City and set the ORDER BY in DQL. The drawback of this solution is that I have to give Country and City array as two parameters in my twig template, and if the designer use `country.cities` instead of the `cities` parameter it will fail:

```
$country = ...
$cities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MyBundle:City")->findFromCountryOrderedBySize($country);
return $this->render('MyBundle:Section1:index.html.twig', array(
    'country'=>$country,
    'cities'=>$cities
));
```

Comment: You could just `$country->setCities($cities);` in the controller or service then tell your designer to always use `$country->getCities()`. It also might make it more flexible for the future should your order requirements change.

Comment: It may also work better to use a QueryBuilder instead of a repository to have more granular control over the result set. http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html

Comment: @AlexP it's so simple that I did not even though at it ;) It's a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my repository classes I always return a [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) so in my controllers or model manager classes I can adjust the query to be just right rather than having tons of very specific queries.

I got turned on to this by the [Form Component Entity Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) which requires that you provide it a QueryBuilder to do it's work.

Setting [orderBy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) on a QueryBuilder will override any previously set orderBy. You could have a default orderBy then override it in your particular use case or use [addOrderBy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods) to supplement the default order provided by your QueryBuilder. Makes life a lot less messy.

Comment: Really interesting, I had the same problem with Form Component Entity Type but never though at overiding the orderBy on the QueryBuilder. I'll look at that!

Comment: So I finally use your solution and it worked great. I changed my Repository function to use query builder instead of DQL and set the order by from a parameter of the function. The controller just has to call this function with the good parameter to get the country objects with the cities ordered the good way.

Answer (score 1):

When I need finer control over the result set I will use a QueryBuilder. The repo's are nice for a quick findOneBy() call, but not when you have a larger WHERE clause and multiple orderBy definitions.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('c')
   ->from('City', 'c')
   ->orderBy('c.size')
   ->getQuery();

$cities = $query->getResult();
```

The documentation is here: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html

Comment: The findFromCountryOrderedBySize() method from my example use : `SELECT c FROM MyBundle:City c WHERE c.country=:countryId ORDER BY c.size`. It's nearly the same except it use DQL instead of the QueryBuilder. What I really want to avoid is to get two separate objects `country` and `cities` to pass to my template. I would prefer passing only `country` and let the template designer using `country` and `country.cities`.